# set yAxis ticks D3js

Tags: d3.js

I am having time series chart in D3js in that I am setting up yScale like.

```
setYScale() {
      this.yScale = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .range([this.gHeight, 0])
        .domain(this.yData) //this is array [0,1,2,3,4,5....23]
        .padding(0.06);
},
```

This sets tick for me in left side, from 0 to 23 (24hrs), what I would like to achieve is that instead of having it sequential order from 0,1,2,3,4...tick I would like to have 0,2,4,6,8 (even numbers), and rest should work be as it is just ticks I would like to have it as even number. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Can you post your entire code example?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just the scale, assuming you have an axis called `axis`, try:

```
axis.tickFormat(function(d) { return (+d)%2 ? '' : d })
```

Comment: this.yAxisElement.call((g) =>
        g.call(d3.axisLeft(this.yScale).tickSize(0).tickPadding(8).tickValues(this.yScale.domain().filter(el=>el%2===0)).tickFormat(function(d) { return (+d)%2 ? '' : d }))
      ); this did not work